# C# Assign to sub-property of member if member isn't null

Tags: c#, nullable

Is there any way I can assign to a property belonging to a member property, without using a conditional statement such as `if`? UIElement is a class and I am using nullable reference types.

For example:

```
public UIElement? Content { get; set; }
public override void LayoutChildren()
{
    Content.Size = Size;
}
```

However, if `Content` is null, then that will throw a null reference exception. I could, of course use:

```
if (Content is not null)
    Content.Size = Size;
```

But that requires a bulky and ugly `if` statement to do a simple thing.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
Content?.Size = Size;
```

Without using any helper methods (such as an `AssignIfNotNull()` method) or similar.

Comment: Null conditional evaluates to something; can't be the target of an assignment

Comment: @djv However you can use the null conditional operator for a method call (`SomeMember?.SomeMethod()`). If `SomeMember` evaluates to be null, it simply doesn't call the method.

Comment: @lostceiling Yes, same as calling a function without assigning to anything. But a function can't be the target of an assignment the same way.